# Laravel 5.8 Custom Rules - Return False vey slow

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, validationrules

**TLDR; Why does my app take 30+ seconds to reload when a custom rule returns False, whereas less than 1 second when true?**

I made a custom Rule in my Laravel 5.8 app. Whenever it returns true, it takes less than a second for the page to reload. However, when it returns false, it takes about 30+ seconds to reload. Does anyone know how to fix this?

*Note, it doesn't seem to be coming from the API itself, as within Postman it returns the response, whether true or false, in less than a second.

In my controller, I have the Rule and I pass it three parameters:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
     'vat' => ['min:4|max:14', new NewRule($param_1, $param_2, $param_3)],
]);
```

In the rule, I accept these parameters in the `__construct` and use them within the `passes` function.

Construct:

```
public function __construct($param_1, $param_2, $param_3)
{
    $this->param_1 = $param_1;
    $this->param_2 = $param_2;
    $this->param_3 = $param_3;
}
```

Passes

Within the passes function, I send these parameters through an API to validate the given information.

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    $param_1 = $this->param_1;
    $param_2 = $this->param_2;

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "http://api.endpoint.net",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\",\"id\": 1,\"method\": \"Validator\",\"params\": {\"param_1\": \"".$param_1."\",\"param_2\":\"".$param_2."\"} }",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "Accept: */*",
            "Connection: keep-alive",
            "Content-Type: application/json",
            ),
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    $valid_vat = json_decode($response, true)['result']['valid'];

    return $valid_vat ?: false;
}
```

Finally, the `message` that I am returning is:

```
public function message()
{
    return 'Invalid VAT number';
}
```

Thanks for any comments and suggestions! I appreciate it :)

Note that instead of `return $valid_vat ?: false;` I have also tried:

```
if($valid_vat === true){
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Hey guys, thanks for your comments. I ran `url_getinfo($curl)` and got the following:

```
array(26) {
  ["url"]=>
  string(42) "http://api.endpoint.net/"
  ["content_type"]=>
  string(31) "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
  ["http_code"]=>
  int(200)
  ["header_size"]=>
  int(287)
  ["request_size"]=>
  int(490)
  ["filetime"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["ssl_verify_result"]=>
  int(0)
  ["redirect_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total_time"]=>
  float(0.351214)
  ["namelookup_time"]=>
  float(2.8E-5)
  ["connect_time"]=>
  float(0.060498)
  ["pretransfer_time"]=>
  float(0.0606)
  ["size_upload"]=>
  float(116)
  ["size_download"]=>
  float(48)
  ["speed_download"]=>
  float(136)
  ["speed_upload"]=>
  float(330)
  ["download_content_length"]=>
  float(-1)
  ["upload_content_length"]=>
  float(116)
  ["starttransfer_time"]=>
  float(0.351183)
  ["redirect_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["redirect_url"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["primary_ip"]=>
  string(11) "99.999.9.99"
  ["certinfo"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["primary_port"]=>
  int(99)
  ["local_ip"]=>
  string(12) "99.999.9.99"
  ["local_port"]=>
  int(99999)
}
```

Note that I changed the API endpoint, IPs, and ports.

Comment: have you tried analyzing your curl timings? `curl_getinfo($curl)` I'd first check to see if something looks weird there.

Comment: Thanks @FrankProvost , I have added this information here. It doesn't seem like it's a problem, though.

Comment: Your total times says `0.351214` have you posted your result of a non-error (fast) call? 0.35 seconds doesn't seem very long. You'll need to provide the information for the problematic calls to see which times are higher than you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use multiple style in your validation instruction. If you are using array as field validation value you should do it like this:

```php
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'vat' => ['min:4', 'max:14', new NewRule($param_1, $param_2, $param_3)],
]);
```

Comment: I can't say it for sure, but my feeling is that this doesn't solve the actual problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Vitaliy, but I have tried it this way and it has not increased the speed.